# Under 10.8 which file stores the environment variables?

Tags: snow-leopard, command-line, macos

This has been this way since 10.6. There is no `.bashrc` file in the home dictionary but the environment variable `PATH` indeed exists as the result of this command shows:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Anyone know how/where OS X stores environment variables?

Comment: So I can store the long uri of my computer lab in a variable

Comment: You can easily create a `.bashrc` in your home folder yourself, can't you?

Answer (score 4):

The system-wide default path is in `/etc/paths`. The default on a 10.8 system contains the following:

> /usr/bin
>
> /bin
>
> /usr/sbin
>
> /sbin
>
> /usr/local/bin

To add additional system-wide `PATH` entries, you could change that file, but a better option would be to add a file with the additional path entries to directory `/etc/paths.d`. That user-created file will be protected during any upgrades/patches, which may replace a customised `/etc/paths` with an Apple-distributed version.

Alternatively, you could put the appropriate `PATH` modifying statements in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc` (in the case of bash, it will only use the latter if the former doesn't exist). Any other system-wide environment changes can be done using those files as well.

User-specific configuration can be put in `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`.

**Note:** In the above, I've assumed you're using bash - if you're using csh or zsh, you'll need to adjust their configuration files (the information about `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d` remains valid, however).

Comment: On OS X, `.bash_profile` is indeed the correct name for the configuration file.

Comment: `.bashrc` is still used for non-login interactive shells (see the manual page for more information).

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own `.profile` or `.bashrc` file to set environment variables for your user.

Answer (score 0):

Where setting environmental variables for a shell which file you use is dependent on what shell you are running.

To determine what shell your running in the Terminal try:

`echo $SHELL`

Once you have that you can read the manual page for your shell, which is likely going to be bash.

`man bash`

If you are running bash, this [segment from the bash manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/bash.1.html) will be helpful.

> When  bash  is  invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login
>          option, it first reads and executes commands from the file **/etc/profile**, if that file exists.   After
>          reading  that  file,  it looks for **~/.bash_profile**, **~/.bash_login**, and **~/.profile**, in that order, and
>          reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The  --noprofile  option
>          may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.